# AngularJS: How can I get the DOM element from a filter

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom, angularjs-filter

The problem is as follows:
I have got several html sites where a filter ("myFilter") is applied.

```
    angular.module('myApp', [])
    .filter('myFilter', function() {
            return function(input) {
                //do something with the input
                return input;
            };
    })
```

The filter is applied within different tags with no special id's or classes, like so:

```
    <span>{{'some_string | myFilter'}}</span>
```

or

```
    <div>{{'some_other_sring' | myFilter}}</div>
```

I would now like to add classes or styles to the elements in which the filter is used (for some testing purposes). My question is, if there is a way to get the DOM elements in the filter function? At the moment I don't see a straight forward way of doing it and would be thankful for a specific or general idea of how to achieve it.
Thanks in advance for any help.

P.S.
I know I could use a directive instead of the filter but, the filter is already distributed in tons of html so I would prefer to work with the filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do that using filter. Use directive instead. For example:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            element.addClass('some-class');
            ...
        }
    };
});
```

Using regex find/replace it won't be too hard to add a directive to all elements that use the filter you wanted to accomplish this with.

Comment: Ok, so it is as I thought. Thank you for your Answer.